# ¿Por qué la diferencia entre los metodos?

Tags: javascript

```js
var A = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
 
var a = new A('alpha');
a.name; // 'alpha'
 
A.prototype = {x: 23}
 
console.log(a.x);

/* ================================== */

var A = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
 
var a = new A('alpha');
a.name; // 'alpha'
 
A.prototype.x = 23;
 
console.log(a.x); // 23
```

Por que en la segunda forma de ingresar con el `prototipo` , da correctamente *23* y en otro `undefined`?, entonces ***como accedo*** a `{x: 23}` ? ***donde esta*** y **cual es el error**?

Comment: Tienes varias preguntas muy parecidas, que casi parecen el mismo concepto preguntado de manera diferente

Comment: Parece que crees que al hacer `A.prototype = {x: 23}` estás asignado el prototipo del objeto `a` . No es así.  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68559/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-el-prototipo-de-un-objeto/68692#68692

Answer (score 2):

El constructor `A` tiene un prototipo ya definido, en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) todas las funciones tienen un prototipo. Sin embargo, **luego** de crear un objeto con el prototipo de `A` **reasignas** un nuevo prototipo; sin embargo, el objeto **mantiene una referencia** hacia el prototipo original.

Puedes darte cuenta de esto haciendo tan solo asignando el nuevo prototipo **antes** de crear un objeto:

```js
const A = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
};

A.prototype = {x: 23}
 
const a = new A('alpha');
a.name; // 'alpha'
 
console.log(a.__proto__);
```

Ahora mira lo que imprime cuando lo pones a tu manera:

```js
const A = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
 
const a = new A('alpha');
a.name; // 'alpha'
 
A.prototype = {x: 23}
 
console.log(a.__proto__);
```

Para entender más sobre cómo funcionan los prototipos en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) te recomiendo [este artículo](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/) de [Yehuda Katz](https://twitter.com/wycats).

Comment: La respuesta es correcta. Pero la primera frase puede causar confusión. Toda función tiene, en efecto, un atributo (visible, accesible)  llamado `prototype`. Por otro lado, todo objeto en Javascript (no solo las funciones) tienen "un prototipo", que es una referencia oculta a otro objeto. El atributo `A.prototype` _no_ es el prototipo de la función  `A`,  ni del objeto `a`   - es el prototipo que se asignará en lo sucesivo a todo objeto construido (con `new`) mediante esa función. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68559/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-el-prototipo-de-un-objeto/68692#68692